# Выборка SQL из 2 таблиц БД

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, выборка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты скрипта для выборки.
Есть 2 таблицы: клиенты и продукты (купленные клиентом).
Надо выбрать всех клиентов, которые купили продукты на сумму свыше 5 тыс. рублей.
Продукты клиенты покупали в рублях и долларах(курс доллара=65 рублей). Есть поле код валюты в таблице продукты(код рубля 1 и код доллара 2).

Comment: Вы хоть схему таблиц покажите.

Comment: _"выбрать всех клиентов, которые купили продукты на сумму"_ -- наверное надо за какой-то период времени?

Comment: Без схемы - затрудняюсь

Comment: Не за период, а всех клиентов сделавших покупку на сумму более 5 тыс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Схема таблиц, конечно, очень помогла бы...
примерно так:

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(decode(p.currency,'RUR',p.price, p.price*65)) 
FROM clients c 
JOIN products p ON p.client_id=c.id 
GROUP BY c.id 
HAVING SUM(decode(p.currency,'RUR', p.price, p.price*65))>5000
```

`RUR` - код валюты рубль.

Может это поможет... сможете в `plsql` перевести...

Знаю, что это не ответ... но SQL похожи, так что хоть подтолкну :)

Comment: _"SUM(IF(p.currency=1, p.price, p.price*65))"_ -- вместо IF будет CASE - так: SUM(case when p.currency=1 then p.price else p.price*65 end)

Comment: Еще в оракле в `group by` надо указать все поля, которые выбираются без агрегатных функций.Так что к сожалению c.* написать будет нельзя. Надо и в `select` и в `group` задать явные списки нужных полей. А ответ ваш я немного поправлю, что бы по диалекту подходил

Comment: Я использую этот вариант, скрипт долго работает. Хз как повысить производительность.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно этот селект будет быстрей ранее предложенного тут

`select c.*, pp.client_sum
    from clients c, 
    (
    SELECT p.client_id, SUM(decode(p.currency,'RUR',p.price, p.price*65)) client_sum
    FROM products p
    GROUP BY p.client_id
    HAVING SUM(decode(p.currency,'RUR', p.price, p.price*65))>5000
    ) pp
    where pp.client_id=c.id`